# How to remove "<>" brackets from string in php?

Tags: php, string

```
$cont=htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents("https://myanimelist.net/anime/30276/One_Punch_Man"));
function getBetween($string, $start = "", $end = ""){
    if (strpos($string, $start)) { // required if $start not exist in $string
        $startCharCount = strpos($string, $start) + strlen($start);
        $firstSubStr = substr($string, $startCharCount, strlen($string));
        $endCharCount = strpos($firstSubStr, $end);
        if ($endCharCount == 0) {
            $endCharCount = strlen($firstSubStr);
        }
        return substr($firstSubStr, 0, $endCharCount);
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
$name=getBetween($cont,'title',' - MyAnimeList.net');
//$name=preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 \p{L}]/m', '', $name);
preg_replace('/(*UTF8)[\>\<]/m', '', $name);
trim($name," ");
//$name=str_replace("gt", "", $name);
echo $name;
```

i want to find the text between title tags. how to do this?
for example in this page title contains 'One Punch Man - MyAnimeList.net' i want to get that

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to remove exactly, but it sounds like you are looking for `strip_tags()`.

Comment: Please provide us some example code.

Comment: The question is unclear. You ask how to remove just brackets from a string, yet show an example where you remove the html tags from a string. Please be clear, and explain your question, and provide any sample code you tried which did not work as you expect.

Answer (score 2):

Just use string replace function:

```
$string = '<BoomBox>';
$string = str_replace('<', '', $string);
$string = str_replace('>', '', $string);
echo $string; // output: Boombox
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: His question was poorly formatted... you may want to change your answer to reflect.

Answer (score 1):

You edited your answer, and we can now see you are dealing with XML/HTML. It's always better to work with the DOM classes. Never use regex! There is a famous Stack Overflow post explaining why never to parse html with regex. Try this solution instead:

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<title>BoomBox</title>');
echo $dom->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->textContent;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php

See it working here https://3v4l.org/EjPQd

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_replace();`, or `strip_tags();`.

**Example** `preg_replace();`:

```
$str = '> One Punch Man';

$new = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 \p{L}]/m', '', $str);
echo $new;
```

> Output: One Punch Man

Above example will only allow a-z, A-Z and 0-9. You can expand this.

---

**Example** `strip_tags();`:

```
$str = '<title> BoomBox </title>';

$another = strip_tags($str);
echo $another;
```

> Output: BoomBox

---

**Documentation:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php // preg_replace();
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php // strip_tags();

Comment: how do i change this to allow any character except <>?

Comment: when i use this i get an & at the start of the string.

Comment: I see! Nice you are creating this. Try to use `strip_tags();` on `$name`. Delete the `trim()` and `preg_replace();` functions. Just use `strip_tags();` to see the results.

Comment: but here i get only '> One Punch Man' in name. will strip tags work on that?

Comment: No, for that you should use `preg_replace()` from the other example. So `strip_tags` is basically needed when you want to echo HTML and delete those tags, `preg_replace` is to delete not allowed characters and replace it with what you want. So for the '<title> .... </title>' you use `strip_tags()`. For '> One Punch Man' you use `preg_replace`  to delete the '>'.

Comment: I have edited my answer, see the `preg_replace()` example.

Comment: when i use strip_tags it gives an empty string

Comment: What does `$name` give after : `$name=getBetween($cont,'title',' - MyAnimeList.net');` ?

Comment: function string_between($string, $start, $end, $inclusive = true){
 $string = " ".$string;
 $ini = strpos($string,$start);
 if ($ini == 0) return "";
 if (!$inclusive) $ini += strlen($start);
 $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
 if ($inclusive) $len += strlen($end);
 return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}
$name=string_between($cont,'title','/title');

Comment: $name='<'.$name.'>';    i changed it to this so title gets included so now '<title>........</title>

Comment: Now use strip_tags ;-). <title> should be removed.

Comment: thats when it gives empty string

Comment: Try to make $name = ‘<title> yeaaa </title>’. Just yeaaa should be left. Currently we are debugging.

Comment: add quotes to both ends?

Comment: Yes, to make it a string. So you can test what works, and what needs to be optimized

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a single call to [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) with the `['<','>']` as the *search* argument:

```php
$string = '<BoomBox>';
echo str_replace(['<', '>'], '', $string) . PHP_EOL;
// => Boombox
```

Or, you may use a regex with [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace) (especially, if you plan on adding more restrictions for in-context matching to it):

```php
echo preg_replace('~[<>]~', '', $string);
// => Boombox
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/6iQ0N).